# Why does jQuery Mobile put JavaScript in the <head>, not at the bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Based on the [jQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html), the `<script>` tags to load jQuery and jQuery mobile should go inside the `<head>` element.

I've always been told to load `<script>` tags at the bottom of the page for better performance. For example: http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/

Is there a reason to prefer one location over the other for jQuery Mobile scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the `<script>` at the bottom is to facilitate faster loading of external elements before code executes, but in **jQM nothing will really show until the pageinit/pageshow events fire**, which is basically jQM's version of document.ready (everything is loaded and the DOM is there etc)

I can imagine in larger sites where you want content to be displayed ASAP this would come in handy, kind of like attaching passive `on` listeners **even before the document.ready** is another trick people use.

But all these speed optimizations don't mean much when you're waiting for a `document.ready` to display anything.